# Android Autocomplete TextView drop down width

Tags: java, android

I want the dropdown of my auto complete TextView to cover the entire screen width. Currently the normal behaviour of the autocomplete textview is such that it covers only the width of the EditText (screenshot below).

How do I do it ? It should look somewhat like the default maps app in android.

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#attr_android:dropDownWidth

By putting the value -1 or fill_parent it should work

Comment: dropDownWidth is a good point. However, it still start from the edit text's left side.

Answer (score 24):

```
autoCompleteTextView.setDropDownWidth(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels);
```

Comment: It's helpful to include a bit of explanation with the code in your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"` in `AutoCompleteTextView` inside xml

```
  <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
        />
```